# Elasticsearch: Sort Alphabetically ignoring Numbers & Special Characters

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How to sort a text field alphabetically, ignoring the special characters & numbers? By default, the special characters come first followed by numbers and alphabets.

What I need is alphabets should be sorted and appear first, followed by numbers and special characters. Is that even possible in **ES 6.3**?

I've tried with the custom analyzer to replace all non-alphabetical characters but it didn't work:

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "alphabets_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "type": "keyword",
        "char_filter": [
          "alphabets_char_filter"
        ]
      }
    },
    "char_filter": {
      "alphabets_char_filter": {
        "type": "pattern_replace",
        "pattern": "[^a-zA-Z\\s\\.]",
        "replacement": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by the following settings at index level:

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "alphabetsStringAnalyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": "lowercase",
        "type": "custom",
        "char_filter": [
          "alphabets_char_filter"
        ]
      }
    },
    "char_filter": {
      "alphabets_char_filter": {
        "type": "pattern_replace",
        "pattern": "[^a-zA-Z]",
        "replacement": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And setting this analyzer in the index mapping as below:

```
"fullName":{
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
                 "raw": {
                     "type": "text",
                     "analyzer": "alphabetsStringAnalyzer",
                     "fielddata": true
                 }
             }
          }
```

Comment: Nice. I was able to use this. I changed the pattern to `[^\p{L}\s]` so that I can keep characters with diacritics and spaces.